# SVN client checkout errors

Tags: linux, svn

I have a situation where I can checkout a repo through tortoise or Eclipse and a browser, but for the life of me cannot do it directly from the cygwin/ Linux command lines. These are the errors :

```
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://BLAH/project/trunk'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'https://BLAH/project/trunk': could not connect to server (https://BLAH)
```

The command I use is :

```
svn checkout --username MYUN --password MYPASS https://BLAH/project/trunk
```

I have set the proxy too. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: I assume you've tried with sudo?

Comment: It's not required on Cygwin and on the local Linux machine I dont need to be root.

Comment: can you ping the remote server?

Comment: I can ping and ssh to it. The certificate is a dodgy, but if Eclipse and tortoise can checkout , I dont see why command live svn client fails.

Comment: just a suggestion. You can use strace to find out exactly what is the error `strace svn checkout --username MYUN --password MYPASS https://BLAH/project/trunk`

Comment: export http_proxy='http://un:pwd@server:port'

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the proxy in ~/.subversion/servers.

On my corporate laptop behind a proxy that requires NTLM authentication I have to run the ntlmaps proxy and set:

```
    Suppose you define them globally, add this at the end of the file:

    http-proxy-host = localhost
    http-proxy-port = 5865
```

I've configured the ntlmaps daemon to prompt me for my password but you could also add it to ~/.subversion/servers.

```
    http-proxy-username = your account
    http-proxy-password = your password
```

You can get ntlmaps from from http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/, extract it locally then edit ntlmaps-0.9.9\server.cfg

```
PARENT_PROXY:<server FQDN>
PARENT_PROXY_PORT:<proxy port>
NT_DOMAIN:<NT DOMAIN>
USER:<USERNAME>
PASSWORD:
```

Hope this helps.